# Output all scripts in one file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, jboss

I have 3 commands that will output to 3 different files.

```
    ./ant process1 > File1
   ./ant process3 > File2
  ./ant process3 > File3
```

How can I combine/merge the output of these commands to one file? 
Plus is there a way to relocate that output file in certain directory? Assuming it automatically saves it in the same directory.

Comment: `cat File{1,2,3} > Allfiles`

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without outputting it to File1, 2 and 3 first? Plus any idea on how to save it in certain directory?

Comment: `cmd1 >> Allfiles; cmd2 >> Allfiles; cmd3 >> Allfiles`. `>>` for append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED: As Rany pointed out, a subshell is unnecessary.
Please also notice that Bash's *group command* ( i.e. `{ list; }` ) must be terminated with a semicolon or a newline.

Sequential:

```
{./ant process1; ./ant process2; ./ant process3; } > File123
```

Asynchronous:

```
{./ant process1 & ./ant process2 & ./ant process3 & } > File123
```

Comment: Will try. Plus any idea on how to save it in a certain directory?

Comment: `(./ant process1; ./ant process2; ./ant process3) > /path/to/my/file`, you can try it with something like `(ls; cd; pwd)` just to see that it works.

Comment: It didn't create the output file anywhere, so either the path command didn't work or something happened.

Comment: Is this just for the /path/to/my/file example or the File123 example as well? Does it work for dummy commands like `(ls; cd; pwd)`?

Comment: The asynchronous example is probably not useful; the output from the three processes will be arbitrarily merged in the final output.

Comment: yes for ls cd it's there. the "file" is the output file name and before that is the path. I just want to move the File123 to certain directory and not keep it in the same directory.

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the path? You might need sudo

Comment: Useless use of a subshell. Moreover executing the commands in the background will give unreliable results. Use `{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; } > output_file` instead.

Comment: Rany: Right, edited.  
chepner: You're right, though I thought I'd mention it anyways for the narrow use case.

Answer (score 2):

```
./ant process1 > /path/to/file
./ant process2 >> /path/to/file
./ant process3 >> /path/to/file
```

Or

```
{ ./ant process1; ./ant process2; ./ant process3; } > /path/to/file
```